# Pressing enter for selection of a dropdown value directly submits form

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I am working with ui-select, and whenever I press enter to select some searched results, the result is selected and the form directly goes on to submit. I cant figure it out, what is the problem.

Here is the HTML I'm using

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" ng-model="address.street" class="form-control"  placeholder="e.g. NUST Campus, H-12">        
            <div class="form_wrapper_error">
                <p ng-show='addressError'>{{addressError}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">City/Town</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <!-- <location-autocomplete bind-value="address.city" coordinates="cityAddInitialCoordinates" placeholder="e.g. Islamabad"> -->
            <ui-select ng-model="$parent.address.city"
                theme="select2"
                reset-search-input="true"
                title="Select City">
                <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select City">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="city as city in cities track by $index"
                    refresh="refreshLocation($select.search)"
                    refresh-delay="0">
                    <div ng-bind-html="city | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
            <div class="form_wrapper_error">
                <p ng-show='cityError'>{{cityError}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Zip</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text"  ng-model="address.zip" class="form-control"  placeholder="e.g. 44000">
            <div class="form_wrapper_error">
                <p ng-show='zipError'>{{zipError}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <button class="btn btn-primary buttt" ng-click="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it would be better if you post all form related code ,that includes form tag also

Comment: its normal behavior of form, it submits form on enter, basically you need to  prevent that event on enter click, by writing directive

Comment: Yes, it is a normal behavior, but select2 and ui-select2 works fine with enter for selection. why I need to write a directive (for a form or particularly ui-select item)?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza because your ui-select has wrap in form..And `ui-select2` & `ui-select` are totally different than each other

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks for the help. I did the same thing what you told me, but by preventing enter button to submit, now I cannot even click the submit button with enter when the enter button is focused...

Comment: you need to made it field specific..i think you applied that event on whole window, that is messing

Answer (score 3):

Solution Found: I was using `<button>`, and the default type of button is submit, so I had to specify the type="button", and the issue is fixed....

Reference: [Found in UI-Select Pull Requests...](https://github.com/gregurco/ui-select/commit/673369ce8b906fa2da610e887a9611f90a15351e)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still struggles with this issue, I found a solution\work around.
Add `skip-focusser="true"` to your ui-select like so:

```
<ui-select ng-model="$parent.ngModel" theme="bootstrap" class="input-xs" skip-focusser="true">
<ui-select-match >{{$select.selected.description}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in options | orderBy :'code' | filter: $select.search">
   <div ng-bind-html="item.description | highlight: $select.search"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

This will remove the focus from the select element and therfore the Enter key will not reopen the dropdown menu.